# passing value from signup to register if validation is true

Tags: java, android, android-studio

passing value  from signup to register if validation is true.these are error i get

> Error:(105, 36) error: variable firstName might not have been initialized
>   Error:(106, 36) error: variable lastName might not have been initialized
>   Error:(107, 36) error: variable mobile might not have been initialized
>   Error:(108, 36) error: variable password might not have been initialized
>   Error:(109, 36) error: variable email might not have been initialized
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

my code given below

```
public class Signup extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup);

    final String firstName;
    final String lastName;
    final String mobile ;
    final String password;
    final String email;

    final EditText edt_Signup_FirstName;
    final EditText edt_Signup_LastName;
    final EditText edt_Signup_Mobile;
    final EditText edt_Signup_Password;
    final EditText edt_Signup_Email;

    Button btn_Signup_Register;

    edt_Signup_FirstName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_first_name);
    edt_Signup_LastName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_last_name);
    edt_Signup_Mobile=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_mobile);
    edt_Signup_Password=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_password);
    edt_Signup_Email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_email);

    btn_Signup_Register=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_signup_register);


    btn_Signup_Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //First Name
            if(edt_Signup_FirstName.length() <8){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "ENTER MINIMUM 8 CHARATER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(edt_Signup_FirstName.length()>=15){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "CAN ENTER MAXIMUM 15 CHARACTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (edt_Signup_FirstName.length() <8 && edt_Signup_FirstName.length()>=15){
                String firstName = edt_Signup_FirstName.getText().toString();
            }
            //Last Name
            if(edt_Signup_LastName.length() <8){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "ENTER MINIMUM 8 CHARATER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(edt_Signup_LastName.length()>=15){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "CAN ENTER MAXIMUM 15 CHARACTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{
                String lastName = edt_Signup_LastName.getText().toString();
            }
            //Mobile
            if(edt_Signup_Mobile.length() == 10){

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "ENTER ONLY 10 DIGIT NUMBER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            String phone = String.valueOf(edt_Signup_Mobile);
            char c  = phone.charAt(0);
            if (c == '8' || c == '9' ||c =='7'){

            }else if( c == '0' ||c == '1' ||c == '2' ||c == '3' ||c == '4' ||c == '5' ||c == '6')
            {
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "INVALID NUMBER BEGINED with" +  " +c",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(edt_Signup_Mobile.length() == 10 && c == '8' || c == '9' ||c =='7'){
                String mobile = edt_Signup_Mobile.getText().toString();
            }
            //Password
            if(edt_Signup_Password.length() <4){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "ENTER MINIMUM 8 CHARATER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(edt_Signup_Password.length()>=15){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "CAN ENTER MAXIMUM 15 CHARACTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(edt_Signup_Password.length() <4 && edt_Signup_Password.length()>=15 ){
                String password = edt_Signup_Password.getText().toString();
            }
            //Email
            if(edt_Signup_Email.length() <8){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "ENTER MINIMUM 8 CHARATER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(edt_Signup_Email.length()>=25){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "CAN ENTER MAXIMUM 25 CHARACTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if (edt_Signup_Email.length() <8 && edt_Signup_Email.length()>=25){
                String email = edt_Signup_Email.getText().toString();
            }



            Intent i =new Intent(Signup.this,Register.class);
            i.putExtra("key_f",firstName);
            i.putExtra("key_l",lastName);
            i.putExtra("key_m",mobile);
            i.putExtra("key_p",password);
            i.putExtra("key_e",email);

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}}


public class Register extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    TextView txt_FirstName,txt_LastName,txt_Mobile,txt_Password,txt_Email;

    txt_Email =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
    txt_FirstName =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_firstName);
    txt_LastName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_lastName);
    txt_Mobile = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_mobile);
    txt_Password = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    String firstname = i.getStringExtra("key_f");
    String lastname = i.getStringExtra("key_l");
    String mobile = i.getStringExtra("key_m");
    String password = i.getStringExtra("key_p");
    String email = i.getStringExtra("key_e");

    txt_Email.setText("EMAIL : " +email);
    txt_FirstName.setText("FIRSTNAME : " +firstname);
    txt_LastName.setText("LASTNAME : " +lastname);
    txt_Mobile.setText("MOBILE : " +mobile);
    txt_Password.setText("PASSWORD : " +password);
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize these variables.

```
final String firstName = "";
final String lastName = "";
final String mobile = "" ;
final String password = "";
final String email = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

First, **final** variables must be inited with value. And never can be changed:

```
final String firstName = "value";
final String lastName = "value";
final String mobile = "value" ;
final String password = "value";
final String email = "value";
```

Next, seems you want to change value of that final variables, but you create new ones, that never used:

```
 else {
    String lastName = edt_Signup_LastName.getText().toString();
 }
```

And then put final variables, that not inited:

```
i.putExtra("key_f",firstName);
```

I suggest you to remove final mod and set value correctly without creating new variables:

```
 String firstName;
 ...
 else {
    firstName = i.putExtra("key_f",firstName);
 }
```

Hopefully you will get correct result.

Answer (score 0):

Try modify your code like this:

```
btn_Signup_Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //First Name
            if (edt_Signup_FirstName.length() <8) {
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "ENTER MINIMUM 8 CHARATER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            } if (edt_Signup_FirstName.length()>=15){
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "CAN ENTER MAXIMUM 15 CHARACTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            String firstName = edt_Signup_FirstName.getText().toString();

            //Last Name
            if (edt_Signup_LastName.length() <8) {
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "ENTER MINIMUM 8 CHARATER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (edt_Signup_LastName.length()>=15) {
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "CAN ENTER MAXIMUM 15 CHARACTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            String lastName = edt_Signup_LastName.getText().toString();

            //Mobile
            if (edt_Signup_Mobile.length() != 10) {
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "ENTER ONLY 10 DIGIT NUMBER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            String phone = String.valueOf(edt_Signup_Mobile);
            char c  = phone.charAt(0);
            if (c == '8' || c == '9' ||c =='7') {

            } else if ( c == '0' ||c == '1' ||c == '2' ||c == '3' ||c == '4' ||c == '5' ||c == '6') {
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "INVALID NUMBER BEGINED with" +  " +c",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            String mobile = edt_Signup_Mobile.getText().toString();

            //Password
            if (edt_Signup_Password.length() <4) {
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "ENTER MINIMUM 8 CHARATER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (edt_Signup_Password.length()>=15) {
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "CAN ENTER MAXIMUM 15 CHARACTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            String password = edt_Signup_Password.getText().toString();

            //Email
            if (edt_Signup_Email.length() <8) {
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "ENTER MINIMUM 8 CHARATER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            if (edt_Signup_Email.length()>=25) {
                Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "CAN ENTER MAXIMUM 25 CHARACTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            String email = edt_Signup_Email.getText().toString();



            Intent i =new Intent(Signup.this,Register.class);
            i.putExtra("key_f",firstName);
            i.putExtra("key_l",lastName);
            i.putExtra("key_m",mobile);
            i.putExtra("key_p",password);
            i.putExtra("key_e",email);

            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three main wrongdoings in your code :


1- not initializing the variables firstname, lastname, .... with proper default strings


2- Redefining String variables with the same name as firstname, lastname , .... .
You can easily just remove the "String" part in the if and else blocks


3- **The most important one :** You miss a final else on your validation block (ifs and elses) for the condition when everything is right. Currently, you are starting the Register Activity, no matter what the user has entered. So, generally your code should look like this :

```
if(edittext_firstname.getText().toString() is not OK)
     //Show proper toast messages
else if (edittext_lastname.getText().toString() is not OK)
     // show proper toast messages
.
.
.
 else
     startActivity(Register) ;
```